# How do you disable trusted.packages check for Spring-Kafka JsonDeserializer?

Tags: java, spring, scala, deserialization, spring-kafka

I have legacy Spring-Scala project. I have added new event type to one of the topics and now consumers throw exceptions

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The class '...' is not in the trusted packages: [java.util, java.lang, ...].
```

It seems that a few classes are always added by Spring. I want to disable this feature but it seems that list of classes must be empty for the code to ignore it. But I don't see how that list would ever be empty if some java packages are added by Spring itself. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got this. There is a method called `.addTrustedPackages` and it handles `"*"` argument as one that clears the internal `trustedPackages` list. Neat design... >.<

So the following code works

```
val deserializer = new JsonDeserializer[...]()
deserializer.addTrustedPackages("*")
```